Flutter IOS Live Activity stops when the app is in background in Production
I've implemented live activity in my flutter app using channel manager but the problem is when the app goes to background the live activity stops in 10 seconds.
It is happening in production app but it's working fine in my local. It's driving me crazy. Can someone help?
Here is the AppDelegate code
let diChannel =  FlutterMethodChannel(name: "DI", binaryMessenger: controller.binaryMessenger)

    diChannel.setMethodCallHandler({ [weak self] (
           call: FlutterMethodCall, result: @escaping FlutterResult) -> Void in
                switch call.method {
                case "startLiveActivity":
                    self?.liveActivityManager.startLiveActivity(
                        data: call.arguments as? Dictionary<String,Any>,
                        result: result)
                    break

                case "updateLiveActivity":
                    self?.liveActivityManager.updateLiveActivity(
                        data: call.arguments as? Dictionary<String,Any>,
                        result: result)
                    break

                case "stopLiveActivity":
                    self?.liveActivityManager.stopLiveActivity(result: result)
                    break

                default:
                    result(FlutterMethodNotImplemented)
            }
       })

Here is how I am calling in Flutter
class MapPage extends StatefulWidget {

  MapPage({super.key});

  @override
  _MapPageState createState() => _MapPageState();
}

class _MapPageState extends State<MapPage> with WidgetsBindingObserver {

final DynamicIslandManager diManager = DynamicIslandManager(channelKey: 'DI');


@override
  void initState() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
    super.initState();
    diManager.startLiveActivity(
      jsonData: DynamicIslandStopwatchDataModel(elapsedTime: 0, distance: 0).toMap(),
    );
  }


@override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) async {
    print("AppLifecycleState: $state");
    super.didChangeAppLifecycleState(state);
    switch (state) {
      case AppLifecycleState.inactive:
        print("AppLifecycleState: $state");
        break;
      case AppLifecycleState.paused:
        timer = Timer.periodic(
          const Duration(seconds: 1),
              (Timer t) async {
            print("Jogging time: ${joggingTime.inSeconds}, effectiveDistance: $effectiveDistance, stepCount: $stepCount, distance: $distance");
            await diManager.updateLiveActivity(
              jsonData: DynamicIslandStopwatchDataModel(
                  elapsedTime: joggingTime.inSeconds + 1,
                  distance: (effectiveDistance * 1000).round()
              ).toMap(),
            );
          },
        );
        print("AppLifecycleState: $state");
        break;
      case AppLifecycleState.resumed:
        print("AppLifecycleState: $state");
        break;
      case AppLifecycleState.detached:
        print("AppLifecycleState: $state");
        break;
      case AppLifecycleState.hidden:
        print("AppLifecycleState: $state");
        break;
      default:
        print("AppLifecycleState: $state");
        break;
    }
  }
}

I've tried sending messages via DIManager and it's working in my development environment but won't work in live app. Here is the app link if you would like to check it out: https://onelink.to/gmsnme

When the app goes into the background, it cannot process updates unless specific conditions are met. To enable real-time updates, use APNS or FCM.

I've given permission to access location in background and I don't want to send notifications. I'm building app similar to Strava/Runkeeper which keeps track of location while you're walking. I'm sure they don't use realtime notifications as I've tested they work without internet. Can you please suggest ways to do it without having to send notifications?

Ensure the background functionalities are handled properly. If it is functioning in the background, it should update the live activity. Try logging to check if it is functioning correctly after 30-60 seconds.
